# Making Spring gem work with SimpleCov

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, cucumber

I am using `spring` gem to speed up my `rspec` and `cucumber` tests.
I have the following config in both my `spec/spec_helper.rb` and `features/support/env.rb` files:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

If I start my tests with `rspec spec/` and `rake cucumber:ok`, than SimpleCov merges reports and I get what I wanted.
But if I use `spring rspec spec/` and `spring cucumber features/`, each command overwrites previous report and doesn't merge them.
How can I make `spring` merge reports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a name for each report, so that Simplecov knows that they are to be merged. Simplecov tries to discover the command but the spring command makes it impossible, so do it manually.

So in `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
SimpleCov.command_name "RSpec"
```

And in `features/support/env.rb`:

```
SimpleCov.command_name "Cucumber"
```

Remember to stop the spring server so the change takes effect:

```
spring stop
```

[More info](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#test-suite-names)